# Adding/removing object to mutable array

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsmutablearray

I have **allSpecialities** array, and **selectedSpecialities** array. I'm downloading those arrays from the server, parse them to object and adding them to those arrays. Now, I want to check/uncheck some specialities. I've tried with `containsObject`, but that's not working, because those objects are not on the same memory location. This is code that I've done so far, and it's working, but I have problem how to add them to this array.
in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`:

```
for (Speciality *specTemp in self.selectedSpecialities) {
        if (speciality.specialityId == specTemp.specialityId) {
            cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
            break;
        }
        else {
            cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
        }
    }
```

in `didSelect`:

```
Speciality *speciality = [[Speciality alloc]init];
    speciality = self.allSpecialities[indexPath.row];
    NSMutableArray *tempSelectedSpecialities = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithArray:self.selectedSpecialities];
    int i=0;
    for (Speciality *tempSpeciality in tempSelectedSpecialities) {
        if (tempSpeciality.specialityId == speciality.specialityId) {
            [self.selectedSpecialities removeObjectAtIndex:i];
        }
        else {

        }
        i++;
    }

    [self.delegate companySpecialities:self.selectedSpecialities];
    [self.specialitiesTableView reloadData];
```

Comment: Beginners mistake: In didSelect, you create a Speciality object, and then immediately overwrite it. Don't do that.

Comment: Can you explain me how to do that on other way?

Comment: `Speciality *speciality = self.allSpecialities[indexPath.row];` like this.

Comment: Ok, but that not solved my problem.

Comment: If you want `containsObject:` to work, you need to implement `isEqual:`, and I think, `hash`.

Comment: Where? I'm pretty stuck here...

Comment: If specialityId is a string, use isEqualString.  Like so: if ([tempSpeciality.specialityId  isEqualString:speciality.specialityId])

Comment: But using NSPredicate is probably a better solution in this case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have declare one Mutable array in .h to store a data

```
 NSMutableArray *selectedMarks;
```

assign memory in viewDidLoad

```
selectedMarks = [NSMutableArray new];
```

add and remove object in didSelectRowAtIndexPath

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
   TableViewCell *cell = (TableViewCell *)[self.tblview cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];


    NSString *strIndex=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld",(long)indexPath.section];

    if ([selectedMarks containsObject:strIndex])// Is selected?
    {
        [selectedMarks removeObject:strIndex];
    }
    else{
        [selectedMarks addObject:strIndex];
        }
}
```

in cellForRowAtIndexPath

```
    - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {
        static NSString *CRTableViewCellIdentifier = @"TableViewCell";
        TableViewCell *cell = (TableViewCell *)[self.tblview dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CRTableViewCellIdentifier];
        if (cell == nil) {
            cell = [[TableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CRTableViewCellIdentifier];
        }
        cell.backgroundColor=[UIColor colorWithRed:122/255.0 green:196/255.0 blue:251/255.0 alpha:1];

        // Check if the cell is currently selected (marked)
           NSString *txtQRCodeid = [[[dictListQR objectForKey:@"boxlist"]objectAtIndex:indexPath.section]valueForKey:@"qr_code_id"];

NSString *text1 = [[[dictListQR objectForKey:@"boxlist"]objectAtIndex:indexPath.section]valueForKey:@"box_name"];
        NSString *text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"QR Code %ld with %@",indexPath.section+1,text1];

         cell.isSelected = [selectedQR containsObject:txtQRCodeid] ? YES : NO;
        if (cell.isSelected) {
            [cell.btnSelection setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"check"] ];
            // set image of selected
        }
        else{
            [cell.btnSelection setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"uncheck"] ];
            // set unselected image
        }
     cell.lblQRcodeText.text=text;
   cell.textLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:15];
        return cell;
       }
```

It's Work for me